# Find all numbers that are present more then 3 times in a column of CSVs

Tags: mysql

I basically want this: `if certain number is present >= 3 times then do some action ...`

My table's column is this: [image]

As you can see here that number `38` is present >= 3 times in `absent_sids` column, so I want to have some actions on him like ban or something else. But I don't know what sql query should I write because;
1. I am quite new to php/mysql
2. The column has comma separated numbers, and its quite difficult for me to search in this column through mysql query and bring the `absent_sid` that is >= 3 times in a given period of time/date.

Plz help

Comment: use like and HAVING COUNT(*)>=3

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, can you plz write a query and show me exactly what you mean?

Comment: Would it be possible to add another table for `absent_sids` so that it is not comma-separated values? That way you would not have this problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I thought the same previously but actually I have a lot of work on this table already and I want to use it only.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <yourtable> WHERE absnt_sids like '38,%'`.

Comment: You still need the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in this table so that you can pinpoint where the duplicates are. Please show us the other columns in your table.

Comment: @FDavidov what if 38 is not the prefix?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, I just updated the question with the complete table's image

Comment: Columns with comma separated lists of data are a really bad design. This will cause you nothing but trouble for as long as you maintain this poor design choice.

Comment: @cdaiga, if the prefix can change, it would e held in a variable (say `@prefix`) so: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <yourtable> WHERE absnt_sids like @prefix + ',%'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite long but working.  Steps:  1) convert the array into rows using CHAR_LENGTH and REPLACE function.  2) Use GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT to search for numbers that exists 3 or more times

See demo here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39afc0/2

```
    SELECT absent_sids
    from (
     SELECT
      tablename.aid,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          tablename.absent_sids, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) as absent_sids
     FROM
      (select ORDINAL_POSITION as n
         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where table_name='COLUMNS' 
          and ORDINAL_POSITION <= (
                       select round(max(length(absent_sids))/2) 
                       from tablename)) numbers 
     INNER JOIN tablename
     ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.absent_sids)
        -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.absent_sids, ',', '')) 
          >= numbers.n-1) tab
    GROUP BY absent_sids
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: did you see my sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa6d2/13. Do you want the entire row or just absent_sids?

Comment: I edited my answer to show just the absent_sids. Please check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39afc0/2